# Why my textview deosn't show up, I can see it on the preview in my XML file but not on my app? (Android)

Tags: java, android, android-studio

My textview shows up in the code preview, but not when I run the app.  I have had this issue for another page and can not resolve it. I'm not really sure why this is happening. I've been playing with a lot of different things in the code and none seem to work.

Below is the code for my XML file and my activity:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:fillViewport="true"
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">



<TextView
    android:id="@+id/provider_title"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_below="@id/moreInfoPicture"
    android:layout_height="30dp"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="0dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="25dp"
    />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/about_the_provider"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_below="@id/provider_title"
    android:layout_height="30dp"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="0dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="25dp"
    android:text="About the provider"
    />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/more_info_text"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_below="@id/about_the_provider"
    android:layout_height="250dp"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="25dp"
    />



  <ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/moreInfoPicture"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="300dp"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="0dp"
    android:padding="0dp"

    />




</RelativeLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

Here is the code for my activity:

```
 package com.example.leoconnelly.connexus;

import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Typeface;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.text.method.ScrollingMovementMethod;
import android.widget.ImageButton;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.squareup.picasso.Picasso;

import java.util.ArrayList;

/**
 * Created by leoconnelly on 4/11/18.
 */

public class MoreInfoActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    ImageButton moreInfoImage;
    TextView moreInfoText;
    TextView AboutProv;
    TextView ProvName;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.more_info);

       Context mContext = this;

        Typeface buttonFont = Typeface.createFromAsset(this.getAssets(),  "fonts/Roboto-Regular.ttf");
        Typeface boldFont = Typeface.createFromAsset(this.getAssets(),  "fonts/Roboto-Bold.ttf");

        AboutProv = findViewById(R.id.about_the_provider);
        AboutProv.setTypeface(boldFont);
        AboutProv.setTextColor(000000);
        AboutProv.setText("About the provider:");
        AboutProv.setTextSize(30);

        ProvName = findViewById(R.id.provider_title);
        ProvName.setTypeface(boldFont);
        ProvName.setTextColor(000000);



        // moreInfoImage.findViewById(R.id.moreInfoPicture);
        moreInfoText = findViewById(R.id.more_info_text);
       // moreInfoImage = findViewById(R.id.moreInfoPicture);

//get array

        final ArrayList<HealthCenterButton> healthCentersList = HealthCenterButton.getHealthCentersFromFile("healthCenters.json", this);
        final ArrayList <String> miniList = new ArrayList <String>();


        for (HealthCenterButton healthCenterButton : healthCentersList) {
            miniList.add(healthCenterButton.mini);
           System.out.println("BEEEP BEEP BEEP BOOP BOP BEEPED BOOP BEEP");
            System.out.println(miniList);
       }



       //set up array for mini iamges







        /*
        ImageView iw= (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView1);

         */


        //make it scrollable
        moreInfoText.setMovementMethod(new ScrollingMovementMethod());

       // int index = getIntent(index);

        int index = getIntent().getExtras().getInt("index");

        //String intentStringNumber = getIntent().getStringExtra("index");

//        int index = Integer.parseInt(intentStringNumber);

      // int index = 0;

        System.out.println(index +" BOOOP BOP BOOP BOOP BOPP BOOP");

        if (index == 7) {
            //Bowdoin

            moreInfoText.setText("Founded in Boston's Dorchester neighborhood in 1972 by community residents, " +
                    "Bowdoin Street Health Center remains focused on providing outstanding medical care while" +
                    " maintaining a tradition of working with residents to identify and meet their " +
                    "unique health needs. The mission of the health center is to provide excellent, " +
                    "compassionate care to our patients and support the health of the entire community.");
            //Picasso.with(mContext).load(miniList.get(1)).into(moreInfoImage);
           // moreInfoImage =
            //        Picasso.with(mContext).load(healthCenterButton.imageUrl).into(thumbnailImageView);

          // ProvName.setText("Bowdoin Street Health Center");
            AboutProv.setText("About the provider:");



        }

        else  if (index == 7) {
            //BIDMC Chelsea

            moreInfoText.setText("In the midst of a thriving Chelsea neighborhood, " +
                    "we bring world-class health care to patients north of Boston. " +
                    "Our patients have the best of all worlds: dedicated staff, the atmosphere of a private practice, " +
                    "and access to the expertise, resources, and systems of Beth Israel Deaconess Medical Center.");

           // ProvName.setText("BIDMC Chelsea");
        }

        else  if (index == 2) {
            //BIDMC
            moreInfoText.setText("Beth Israel Deaconess Medical Center (BIDMC) in Boston, Massachusetts is a teaching hospital of Harvard Medical School. It was formed out of the 1996 merger of Beth Israel Hospital (founded in 1916) and New England Deaconess Hospital (founded in 1896). Among independent teaching hospitals, Beth Israel Deaconess Medical Center consistently ranks in the top three recipients of biomedical research funding from the National Institutes of Health. Research funding totals nearly $200 million annually. BIDMC researchers run more than 850 active sponsored projects and 200 clinical trials. " +
                    "The Harvard-Thorndike General Clinical Research Center, " +
                    "the oldest clinical research laboratory in the United States, " +
                    "has been located on this site since 1973");
           // ProvName.setText("Beth Israel Deaconess Medical Center (BIDMC)");


        }

        else  if (index == 1) {
            //Dimock Community Health Center Complex
            moreInfoText.setText("Recognized nationally as a model for the delivery of comprehensive health and human services in an urban community, The Dimock Center provides the residents of Boston with convenient access to high quality, low cost health care and human services that might not otherwise be available to the communities we serve. " +
                    " In 2013, Dimock handled over 76,000 visits annually with 17,000 unique patients and " +
                    "clients representing a wide range of socioeconomic and ethnic backgrounds.");

            //ProvName.setText("Dimock Community Health Center");


        }

        else  if (index == 4) {
            //Fenway Health
            moreInfoText.setText("For more than forty years, " +
                    "Fenway Health has been working to make life healthier for the people in our neighborhood, " +
                    "the LGBT community, people living with HIV/AIDS and the broader population. Fenway was " +
                    "founded in 1971 as part of the free clinic movement by students who believed that" +
                    " ''health care should be a right, not a privilege. In its early days, " +
                    "Fenway was a drop-in clinic providing free blood pressure checks and STD screenings. Over the years, Fenway obtained permanent space and incorporated as a freestanding health center with a staff of one volunteer doctor, one nurse and one intake worker. Today, Fenway Health has a budget of more than $90 million, a staff of 500 and a patient population of more than 28,000. " +
                    "Fenway Health is a Federally Qualified Community Health Center.");
          //  ProvName.setText("Fenway Health");

    }

    else  if (index == 5) {
        //South Cove Medical Center

        moreInfoText.setText("South Cove Community Health Center ('South Cove') is the premier Asian community health center of Massachusetts. Founded in 1972, South Cove provides medical and behavioral health services and youth and family programs for approximately 32,000 clients at four locations in the greater Boston area. Our mission is to improve the health and well being of all medically underserved in Massachusetts, with a special focus on Asian Americans.  " +
                "This mission is accomplished by providing high quality, " +
                "community-based health care and health promotion programs " +
                "that are accessible and linguistically and culturally competent for these populations.");
       // ProvName.setText("South Cove Medical Center");

    }

    else  if (index == 6) {
        //South Cove Chinatown
        moreInfoText.setText("South Cove Community Health Center ('South Cove') is the" +
                " premier Asian community health center of Massachusetts. 
  Founded in 1972, South Cove provides medical and" +
                " behavioral health services and youth and family programs for 
  approximately 32,000 clients at four locations in the greater Boston area. " +
                "Our mission is to improve the health and well being of all 
 medically underserved in Massachusetts, with a special focus on Asian 
  Americans. " +
                " This mission is accomplished by providing high quality," +
                " community-based health care and health promotion programs" +
                " that are accessible and " +
                "linguistically and culturally competent for these 
     populations");
      //  ProvName.setText("South Cove China Town");



    }




}
}
```

Comment: Which TextView does not show up? Can you add a screenshot of the preview and one of the app?

Answer (score 0):

TRY THIS

```
 <ScrollView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fillViewport="true"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <RelativeLayout 
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
```

I havnt tried but it seems like you scroll view is overlaying the layout try this and let me know

Answer (score 0):

Try below :

```
text.setTextColor(Color.parseColor(Color.BLACK));
```

or

```
text.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#FFFFFF"));
```

instead of

```
ProvName.setTextColor(000000);
```

Answer (score -1):

Try:

```
public ImageButton moreInfoImage;
public TextView moreInfoText;
public TextView AboutProv;
public TextView ProvName;
```

or

```
public ImageButton moreInfoImage;
public TextView moreInfoText, AboutProv, ProvName;
```

You define the TextViews in a protected and class specific method. This causes issues with the display of the activity outside of the onCreate method.

Also you should avoid using an uppercase letter as the first letter in your variable. That's not proper camel-casing methodologies.

For clarity I'd change:

- AboutProv to aboutProv
- ProvName to provName

everywhere mentioned in your code.

Comment: "You define the TextViews in a protected and class specific method. This causes issues with the display of the activity outside of the onCreate method. " - this is wrong on several accounts: OP does *assign values* to fields (= variables visible everywhere in the class) in `onCreate()` . The fields are declared/ defined outside of the method. It is perfectly ok to have these fields `private`. While it is correct that one should not let variable names begin with an uppercase letter, it does not help OP to solve the problem. So it should not be posted as an answer but as a comment.

Comment: Where is your evidence to suggest that is the case. I've personally run into problems with modern Android app development where Views not declared public and modified have display issues. Also if OP hasn't tested the theory to prove this is not a solution why specifically down vote the concept? I can agree with the camel casing comment I can edit my state to reflect the suggestion.

Comment: Is there any evidence in either the code or the question text that OP uses anything related to "modern Android app development"? I don't think so. Maybe you should edit your answer and mention the tools/ frameworks you are referring to. That way, your answer can actually become very helpful, at least for future readers

Comment: Hey buddy don't get upset I'm just trying to help the OP. Funny enough I wasn't using any tools or frameworks. I just ran into the same problem with a side project I was developing. I said modern because I'm not aware of view display compatibility issues with Android versions predating certain API levels.

Comment: Thank you for staying friendly despite my criticism.
 Please understand that the one thing which I don't like about your answer is that newbies could get the impression that one always has to do 
like your answer suggests or else their code won't work. I am not even able to reproduce OP's issue on my machine
 (with, of course, my own Android Studio version and build tools version and gradle version...). I've written code like this more often than I care to count and until now I did not run into any problems. (cont)

Comment: (cont)  So I think the reason must be something else which OP unfortunately did not mention. Do you think you could rephrase you answer to sound a little bit less 100%-ish?

Comment: I tested my answer but unfortunately the negative feedback doesn't show show this as solved. it's far too long down the road now for the OP to still care but my reputation is soiled. What do you mean by 100%-ish. I only talk of which I know

Comment: "I tested my answer" - does this mean that you were able to reproduce OP's issue: app is not crashing but text does not show? And if you switch from package protected Views to public Views, then the text is visible?